# Why use Conditionnel Passé "j'aurais voulu", not Conditionnel Présent "je voudrais"?

Tags: temps-grammatical

> Vous feriez mieux d’aller sans moi. J'**aurais voulu** vous accompagner, mais j'**ai** besoin de faire ...
>
> {instead of}: Vous feriez mieux d’aller sans moi. Je **voudrais** vous accompagner, mais j'**ai** besoin de faire ...

In this specific instance, you can still change your mind and go with them, so it seems more logical to use Conditionnel Présent "je voudrais ... (si je pouvais)". Why is Conditionnel Passé preferred here?

If you are talking about what has already happened in the past, on the other hand, it makes perfect sense to use Conditionnel Passé "j'aurais voulu":

> J'**aurais voulu** vous accompagner, mais j'**avais** besoin de faire ...

Comment: As long as there's still time (and desire) to change your mind, couldn't you even use the present indicative (especially if you were actually hoping that someone would twist your arm a bit)?  With this personal interpretation of "j'en veux, mais ..." as perhaps meaning  "I really want to go so please twist my arm" in mind, **maybe** using the conditional (especially the past conditional) **might** be implying that the decision is final, and since you no longer can/want to go there's no use insisting (?and **perhaps** even that there was really never much desire to go in the first place?).

Comment: Hi. En fait, j'en ai moi aussi déduit qu’il s'agissait peut-être là de « Mon choix est déjà gravé dans la pierre. Ne t'embête donc pas à essayer de me faire changer d'avis ! ». L'emploie du conditionnel présent, par contre, semble laisser entendre que « je peux encore me laisser convaincre ».

Comment: Autre chose : "je voudrais" est souvent employé pour dire "je veux" de façon plus polie, en insistant moins. "Je voudrais que tu viennes" = "viens, si tu veux me faire plaisir" tandis que "Je veux que tu viennes" = "viens, c 'est un ordre." Donc peut-être que "j'aurais voulu" signifie seulement que l'élément qui empêche mon désir de venir de se réaliser n'est pas la volonté de mon interlocuteur, mais autre chose sur lequel il n'a aucune prise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The past conddional is used to :

- give uncertain information, non-confirmed

par exemple : D'après Marc, il aurait demandé à changer de poste

- express a regret

par exemple : Si j'avais su qu'il pleuvait, j'aurais pris un parapluie

- express a prior action to another action at present conditional.

par exemple : Il a dit qu'il viendrait (conditionnel présent) dès qu'il aurait terminé (conditionnel passé) la vaisselle.

Also, in your example "Vous feriez mieux d’aller sans moi. J'aurais voulu vous accompagner, mais j'ai besoin de faire ...", this is the regret which expressed. It means you can still change your mind and go with them too. 
The present conditional doesn't express regret, that's the difference between the two phrases.

The present conditional is used to :

- give an uncertain information, non-confirmed

par exemple : D'après Jean, il serait sur le point d'arriver.

- express a futur in the past

par exemple : Il dit (présent) qu'il ira (futur) avec nous.
Il a dit (passé) qu'il irait (conditionnel) avec nous.

- make hypothesis, express an eventuality

par exemple : Travailler à distance pourrait me convenir.

- ask politely, propose, express a wish, advise

par exemple: Pourriez-vous m'indiquer la sortie, s'il vous plaît.
J'aimerais beaucoup partir en vacances au soleil.